# solo me imprime 6 valores en ves de 12

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, variables

Estaba haciendo el *script* de unas fórmulas y necesito que me imprima el valor de cada mes, para luego sumarlo; pero no me imprime todos los valores como debe,  solo imprime 6 y no los 12 que yo espero.  Si no imprime todos no podre realizar la suma y no me deja avanzar a la otra fórmula.

¿Alguien sabe qué error tiene mi código?

Ya estuve revisando todo, faltas de ortografía, y no se como solucionarlo. Ya modifiqué también todas las variables y también les cambie de nombre y no encuentro el error. Yo pensaba que era por que algunos daban el mismo valor, pero no, porque también entre los 6 que si imprime, algunos dan el mismo valor.

Después comente los 6 que aparecen y aparecieron los otros.

```js
  var enero = 1;
  var enero1 = 0.793;
  var enero2 = 0.956;
  var enero3 = 2.802;
  var febrero = 2;
  var febrero1 = 0.793;
  var febrero2 = 0.956;
  var febrero3 = 2.802;
  var marzo = 3;
  var marzo1 = 0.793;
  var marzo2 = 0.956;
  var marzo3 = 2.802;
  var abril = 4;
  var abril1 = 0.793;
  var abril2 = 0.956;
  var abril3 = 2.802;
  var mayo = 5;
  var mayo1 = 0.569;
  var mayo2 = 0.718;
  var mayo3 = 1.727;
  var mayo4 = 2.745;
  var junio = 6;
  var junio1 = 0.569;
  var junio2 = 0.718;
  var junio3 = 1.727;
  var junio4 = 2.745;
  var junio = 7;
  var julio1 = 0.569;
  var julio2 = 0.718;
  var julio3 = 1.727;
  var julio4 = 2.745;
  var agosto = 8;
  var agosto1 = 0.569;
  var agosto2 = 0.718;
  var agosto3 = 1.727;
  var agosto4 = 2.745;
  var septiembre = 9;
  var septiembre1 = 0.569;
  var septiembre2 = 0.718;
  var septiembre3 = 1.727;
  var septiembre4 = 2.745;
  var octubre = 10;
  var octubre1 = 0.569;
  var octubre2 = 0.718;
  var octubre3 = 1.727;
  var octubre4 = 2.745;
  var noviembre = 11;
  var noviembre1 = 0.793;
  var noviembre2 = 0.956;
  var noviembre3 = 2.802;
  var diciembre = 12;
  var diciembre1 = 0.793;
  var diciembre2 = 0.956;
  var diciembre3 = 2.802; 



function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value; 
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value; 

  var result1 = document.getElementById("result1");
  var result2 = document.getElementById("result2");
  var result3 = document.getElementById("result3");
  var result4 = document.getElementById("result4");
  var result5 = document.getElementById("result5");
  var result6 = document.getElementById("result6");
  var result7 = document.getElementById("result7");
  var result8 = document.getElementById("result8");
  var result9 = document.getElementById("result9");
  var result10 = document.getElementById("result10");
  var result11 = document.getElementById("result11");
  var result12 = document.getElementById("result12");
  
  result1.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)*enero));
  result2.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)*febrero));
  result3.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* marzo));
  result4.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* abril));
  result5.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mayo));
  result6.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* junio));
  result7.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* julio));
  result8.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* agosto));
  result9.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* septiembre));
  result10.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* octubre));
  result11.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* noviembre));
  result12.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* diciembre));
}
```

```html
<form oninput="calc()">
      <input id="a" type="number" value="0">
      <input id="b" type="number" value="0">
      <input id="c" type="number" value="0"><br>
      <h1>invierno</h1>
      <output id="result1"></output>
      <output id="result2"></output>
      <output id="result3"></output>
      <output id="result4"></output>
      <output id="result11"></output>
      <output id="result12"></output><br>
      <h1>verano</h1>
      <output id="result5"></output>
      <output id="result6"></output>
      <output id="result7"></output>
      <output id="result8"></output>
      <output id="result9"></output>
      <output id="result10"></output>
      
      </form>
```

Comment: Tu error es que no tienes definida la variable `julio`. Al valor 7 le volviste a llamar `junio`. Con esa corrección, _imprime_ los 12 valores, sin la corrección no _imprime_ nada.

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es porque no tienes definida la variable julio. En lugar de eso, estás declarando junio dos veces. Al no tener la declaración de julio, el programa falla y detiene la ejecución hasta el mes de junio.

Cambia tu código por este otro:

```
  var enero = 1;
  var enero1 = 0.793;
  var enero2 = 0.956;
  var enero3 = 2.802;
  var febrero = 2;
  var febrero1 = 0.793;
  var febrero2 = 0.956;
  var febrero3 = 2.802;
  var marzo = 3;
  var marzo1 = 0.793;
  var marzo2 = 0.956;
  var marzo3 = 2.802;
  var abril = 4;
  var abril1 = 0.793;
  var abril2 = 0.956;
  var abril3 = 2.802;
  var mayo = 5;
  var mayo1 = 0.569;
  var mayo2 = 0.718;
  var mayo3 = 1.727;
  var mayo4 = 2.745;
  var junio = 6;
  var junio1 = 0.569;
  var junio2 = 0.718;
  var junio3 = 1.727;
  var junio4 = 2.745;
  var julio = 7;        // Aquí debes declarar julio NO junio
  var julio1 = 0.569;
  var julio2 = 0.718;
  var julio3 = 1.727;
  var julio4 = 2.745;
  var agosto = 8;
  var agosto1 = 0.569;
  var agosto2 = 0.718;
  var agosto3 = 1.727;
  var agosto4 = 2.745;
  var septiembre = 9;
  var septiembre1 = 0.569;
  var septiembre2 = 0.718;
  var septiembre3 = 1.727;
  var septiembre4 = 2.745;
  var octubre = 10;
  var octubre1 = 0.569;
  var octubre2 = 0.718;
  var octubre3 = 1.727;
  var octubre4 = 2.745;
  var noviembre = 11;
  var noviembre1 = 0.793;
  var noviembre2 = 0.956;
  var noviembre3 = 2.802;
  var diciembre = 12;
  var diciembre1 = 0.793;
  var diciembre2 = 0.956;
  var diciembre3 = 2.802; 



function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value; 
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value; 

  var result1 = document.getElementById("result1");
  var result2 = document.getElementById("result2");
  var result3 = document.getElementById("result3");
  var result4 = document.getElementById("result4");
  var result5 = document.getElementById("result5");
  var result6 = document.getElementById("result6");
  var result7 = document.getElementById("result7");
  var result8 = document.getElementById("result8");
  var result9 = document.getElementById("result9");
  var result10 = document.getElementById("result10");
  var result11 = document.getElementById("result11");
  var result12 = document.getElementById("result12");

  result1.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)*enero));
  result2.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)*febrero));
  result3.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* marzo));
  result4.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* abril));
  result5.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mayo));
  result6.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* junio));
  result7.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* julio));
  result8.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* agosto));
  result9.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* septiembre));
  result10.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* octubre));
  result11.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* noviembre));
  result12.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* diciembre));
}
```